# What is the complete list of attributes that you can customize for AppCompat Themes and what are their default values?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

Using AppCompatActivity you must extends AppCompat Theme.

What is the complete list of attributes that you can customize, and what is their default value?

I have collected a list of all the ones I've found but do not know if it is complete

help me to complete it

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.AppCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_thumb_material_dark</item>
    <item name="controlBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.Custom.AppCompat.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/button_material_light</item>
    <item name="controlBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
</style>
```

Also, what's the best way to create a custom AppCompat theme in Android?

Comment: Go poke around in the source code... https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml#L32

Comment: i want to create complete list (v7 and android SDK) attr and their default value of each appCompatTheme. actually is not simple to found it

Answer (score 11):

> What is the complete list of attributes that you can customize

That's in these massive highlighted blocks

[Android Source - `Theme.AppCompat` attributes - `res/values/attrs.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/attrs.xml#L34-L395)
[Android Source - base `Theme` attributes - `res/values/attrs.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L24)

> what is their default value?

I'm sure those values are in there somewhere within the `style.xml` files, but there's a lot of those files that you can use Github's search feature to go find.

Note: You don't have to override every value.

The "best way" to make a custom theme? Maybe using the [Theme Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor.html).

Comment: there is some mistakes:
- v7 attr isn't enought, you can use android attr as well in theme
- found default value for base theme is not simple because are in various files (some are in v7 and some are in android sdk)
- theme editor is good but isn't complete with all attr

Comment: Anything with `android:` prefix can be found here. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L24

Comment: I don't know what attribute exactly you are looking for

Comment: There is that value... `<declare-styleable name="AppCompatTheme">`

Comment: a complete list of attr can i use in appCompatThemes and their default values

Comment: I don't have a complete list. If that is all you are asking, I have given you the resources to go find them.

Comment: in this files there are list of attr but not their value in appcompatTheme

Comment: Yes, I know. As I said, all the actual values are within the various styles.xml files (if there even are default values, I dont know)